# ASP MVC - Display One To Many relations in partial view

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

I'm new to ASP MVC and I'm trying to build a simple blog application.

I have the following Posts model :

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.Schema;
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;    

namespace ASPress.Models
{
    public class Posts
    {
        public Posts() => Comments = new HashSet<Comments>();

        [Key, DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
        public long Id { get; set; }
        public string Title { get; set; }
        public string Content { get; set; }
        public string Summary { get; set; }
        public long AuthorId { get; set; }

        [Display(Name = "Published")]
        [DataType(DataType.Date)]

        public DateTime DatePublish { get; set; }

        public Users Author { get; set; }
        public ICollection<Comments> Comments { get; set; }

    }
}
```

And the Comments model :

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;

namespace ASPress.Models
{
    public partial class Comments
    {
        public long Id { get; set; }
        public string Comment { get; set; }
        public long PostId { get; set; }

        public Posts Post { get; set; }
    }
}
```

In my controller, I'm trying to fetch the comments with the post :

```
    public async Task<IActionResult> Details(long? id)
    {
        var posts = await _context.Posts
            .Include(p => p.Author)
            .Include(p => p.Comments)
            .SingleOrDefaultAsync(m => m.Id == id);

        return View(posts);
    }
```

In my post view, I'm calling a partial view that should display the post's comments with :

```
@Html.Partial("Comments", Model.Comments)
```

And the partial view :

```
@model IEnumerable<ASPress.Models.Comments>
<ul>
    @foreach (var item in Model) {
        <li>@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Comment)</li>
    }
</ul>
```

But nothing is showing, even though data is present in the database..
This is mostly code scaffold-ed from the dotnet mvc command tools.

Comment: put a debug point on your partial view and check if the model of your partial view is properly populated and has the values which you want to render.

Comment: Debug your `posts` object in the `Details` method before it is returned to your view and ensure your post comments are populated here.

Comment: Does an id come, since it's nullable? if it's null, there will be no records in th view.

Comment: Well after a full restart I could debug the posts value in the debugger AND the comments is showing up on the page... Weird, is there a caching with the entity framework ... ??